# How do I compare 2 touple values in SQL?

Tags: sql

Lets say i have (the table below). I want to output pid and brand
where pid is not the same value as pid, but color is the same as color, brand is the same as brand. But I cannot use 'red' for color, it has to be ambiguous.

```
CREATE TABLE Paint
     (`pid` int, `color` varchar(20), `finish` varchar(30), `brand`varchar(30))
;
INSERT INTO Paint
(`pid`, `color`, `finish`, `brand`)

VALUES
(1234, 'red', 'matt', 'Walmart'),
(1235, 'cyan', 'gloss', 'behr'),
(1236, 'yellow', 'gloss', 'Lowes'),
(1237, 'green', 'rough', 'HomeDepot'),
(1238, 'red', 'gloss', 'Walmart'),
;
```

This is what i think it is, but what im using results nothing.

```
Select brand, pid
From Paint
Where pid != pid and brand = brand and color = color
```

I want to output

```
PID   BRAND
1234  Walmart
1238  Walmart
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter what i want to show. I am just trying to get the SQL to work. This is just an example for the whole idea of comparing color to color, and having it result in equality or not.

Comment: The query as written just performs the tests against each row (and pid != pid will never be true, while the other two conditions will always be true.) You have to do a self-join and reference the same table as if it were two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a self-join and reference the same table as if it were two different tables.

Adapting your SQL (there are other ways to do it):

```
Select p1.brand, p1.pid
From Paint as p1, Paint as p2
Where p1.pid != p2.pid and p1.brand = p2.brand and p1.color = p2.color
```

Here is a fiddle to show it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9ab5/3

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.brand, a.pid
FROM Paint a, Paint b
WHERE
    a.pid != b.pid
    AND a.brand = b.brand
    AND a.color = b.color
GROUP BY a.brand, a.pid
;
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT? (No aggregate functions involved...)

Comment: @jarlh No particular reason. Anyway, plan should be the same.

Comment: Yeah, I guess most dbms's do the same execution here. You can also do "select UNION same select" and get distinct that way!